# phpmyadmin: how to be sure that two databases data are equal?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've used phpmyadmin to export/import a database from remote server into my localhost, but after importing it, I've found that its total size and numbers are different!

[image: databases size comparison]

- Size for remote Db: 211.9 Mb.
- Size for local Db:  199.9 Mb.

I've exported it using "Compression > gzipped".

I've searched here a lot, and read that differance in size may occuer because of many reasons like indexing for example...

I don't know actually, and don't care, I just want to be sure that data in both of them are equal?

So, I'm wondering if there are a CHECKSUM or something I can query to make sure of that?

Comment: mysqldbcompare https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldbcompare.html

Comment: Uncompress the two files and compare the .sql files directly. You should never compare compressed files because different factors can lead to different output even if the inputs are actually the same (even though some compression formats might produce the exact same output file under certain conditions). Furthermore, the number of rows indicated by MySQL is just an approximation (notice the `~`), so that's not a reliable way to compare databases, either. As @JuanCarlosOropeza said, it's best to use a specific tool for this purpose rather than trying to make it up and hoping for the best.